# Java Communication Server to print 1 million PDF document

Tags: java, itext, openoffice.org

I have a Java batch job which prints 1 million (1 page) PDF document.
This batch job will run after every 5 days.

For printing 1 million (1 Page) PDF document through batch job, which method is better ?

In this PDF most of the text / paragraph is same for all customers, only few information is dynamically picked from database as (Customer Id/ Name/ Due Date/ Expiry Date/ Amount)

We have tried following

1) Jasper Report

2) iText

But above 2 methods are not giving better performance as static text / paragraph for each document is created runtime always.

So I am thinking for some approach like

There will be a template with place holders for dynamic values  (Customer Id/ Name/ Due Date/ Expiry Date/ Amount).

There will be a Communication Server like Open Office, which will have this template.

Through our Java Application deployed on web server will fetch dataset from database and pass onto this communication server, where templates are already opened into memory and just from dataset dynamic placeholder values will be changed and template will be saved like **"Save As"** command.

Can this above approach will be achievable, If yes which API / Communication server is better ?

Here is Jasper Report Code for reference

```
InputStream is = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/jasperreports/reports/"+reportName+".jasper" );    
JasperPrint print = JasperFillManager.fillReport(is, parameters, dataSource);    
pdf = File.createTempFile("report.pdf", "");
JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfFile(print, pdf.getPath());
```

Comment: What was your approach in JasperReports? In Jasper, you can create a `JasperPrint` object, which has the jasper file loaded and just populate it with new data each time.

Comment: One million pages every 5 days ... and another forest dies.  (OK, so you are probably not going to physically print them, but even generating 1 million PDFs is going to chew a lot of resources.)

Comment: Sample Jasper Code is given above

Comment: @Stephen, Using Jasper/iText load is on Web Server, now which we want to distribute on Communication server.

Comment: @RahulAgrawal - that doesn't address my point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a couple of posters mentioned, 1 million PDF files is going to mean you are going to have to sustain a rate of over 2 documents per second.  This is achievable from a pure document-generation aspect, but you need to keep in mind that the load on the systems running the queries and compiling the data will also undergo a reasonable load.  You also haven't said anything about the PDFs - a one page PDF is much easier to generate than a 40 page PDF...

I have seen iText and Docmosis achieve tens of documents per second and so Jasper and other technologies probably could also.  I mention Docmosis because it works along the lines of the technique you mentioned (populating templates loaded into memory).  Please note I work for the company that produces Docmosis.

If you haven't already, you will need to consider the hardware/software architecture and run trials with whatever technologies you are trying to make sure you will be able to get the performance you require.  Presumably the peak-load might be somewhat higher than the average load.

Good luck.

Comment: This job will be running on seperate server which is a good configuration server machine. Onle point here is generating 3-4 (1 Page) PDF document per second.

Answer (score 2):

Wow. 1 million PDF files every 5 days.

Even if it takes you just 0.5 second to generate a PDF file from the beginning to end (a finished file on disk) -  It will take you a FULL 5 days to generate this amount of PDFs sequentially.

I think any approach of generating the file in sub-second amount of time is fine (and Jasper reports certainly can give you this level of performance).

I think you need to think about how you're going to optimise the whole process: you're certainly going to have to use multi-threading and perhaps even several physical servers to generate this amount of files in any reasonable amount of time (at least overnight).

Answer (score 1):

I will go with PDF forms (this should be "fast"):

```
public final class Batch
{
    private static final String FORM = "pdf-form.pdf"

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        final PdfPrinter printer = new PdfPrinter(FORM);
        final List<Customer> customers = readCustomers();

        for(final Customer customer : customers) {
            try {
                printer.fillAndCreate("pdf-" + customer.getId(), customer);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // handle exception
            } catch (DocumentException e) {
                // handle exception
            }
        }

        printer.close();
    }

    private @Nonnull List<Customers> readCustomers() {
        // implements me
    }

    private Batch() {
        // nothing
    }
}

public class PdfPrinter implements Closable
{
    private final PdfReader reader;

    public PdfPrinter(@Nonnull final String src) {
        reader = new PdfReader(src); // <= this reads the form pdf
    }

    @Override 
    public void close() {
        reader.close();
    }

    public void fillAndCreate(@Nonnull final String dest, @Nonnull final Customer customer) throws IOException, DocumentException {
        final PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, new FileOutputStream(dest)); // dest = output
        final AcroFields form = stamper.getAcroFields();
        form.setField("customerId", customer.getId());
        form.setField("name", customer.getName());
        // ...
        stamper.close();
    }
}
```

see also: http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=164